# Transfer eth coins from my desktop wallet to my coinbase exchange account

Tags: transactions, exchanges

I started investing in ethereum using coinbase. I have a wallet which has some coins in it, and I want to move those to my coinbase account. So I tried to send them by getting the address that coinbase provides me, but apparently its not a valid address. I'm unsure whether this is even possible (as in only exchange user accounts can do this sort of transactions)

Anyone ever had a similar issue? Am I missing something?

PS: I know the address is not valid because when clicking on Send it highlights the field in red. The app gave me an address like 0x23uadhauetc and I removed the 0x part.

EDIT: Oddly enough, whether I remove the 0x or not its not valid - the address is not even copied fully

Comment: You shouldn't remove the 0x part

Comment: Still the address doesn't fit :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to transfer ETH to your regular Coinbase account - you don't need an Exchange account.

If you're using the Ethereum Wallet provided by the Mist team, make sure you have the latest version of it installed. It wouldn't hurt to sync the whole Blockchain either - it's probably fastest to do this with the Geth client in your terminal, as the Ethereum wallet for whatever reason is pretty slow at syncing.

Good luck!

Comment: Sadly I don't have a mist wallet, I have an entecoin-qt wallet. However, perhaps the wallet.dat will work for mist as well? Its probably not that easy tho